# c# How can I pass a value from child back to parent?

Tags: c#

I have this project where I'm iterating recursively in some folders and copy them to a new directory.
In the 2nd level of folders (child folder) I have a txt file which I am reading. Now, when I read that file, I parse a string and I want to give that string to the parent folder and assign it as its name. So far I can only do for its File only, because there is accessible but when I try to do it for the parent folder, it doesn't recognize the variable (which of course, makes sense!)

**EDIT: I commented the code so it will be a little bit clearer.**

Now, Is there any way I can achieve this?

Here's my code:

```
    static void CopyDirectory(string sourceDir, string destinationDir, bool recursive)
    {   
        //accessing the directiories inse of Destionationed directory
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDir);
        if (recursive)
        {
            // reading every folder inside first parent folder
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in dirs)
            {
                //reading every folder inside the second folder
                DirectoryInfo[] Subdirs = subDir.GetDirectories();
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir2 in Subdirs)
                {
                    //setting the new path where I want my new files to be stored.
                    string newDestinationDir = Path.Combine(destinationDir, subDir2.Name);

                        //Now, here its where I want to change the main folder's name, but the value must be taking from inside it's file.
                        CopyDirectory(subDir2.FullName, newDestinationDir, true);
                        FileInfo[] SubDirsFiles = subDir2.GetFiles();
                        foreach (FileInfo getFile in SubDirsFiles)
                        {
                            File.Copy(getFile.FullName, newDestinationFile + "_" + dictionary["XECM_DOC_TYPE"], true);
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
          }
```

Note: I'm using Dictiony to story the data I read from file, and thats what I'm trying to pass to the parent folder, exclusively-to the `CopyDirectory(subDir2.FullnName,NewDestinationDir+dictionary["XECM_DOC_TYPE"],true)` but logically it can't recognize the dictionary part because it is declared and initialized inside the FileInfo part...
I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Call CopyDirectory(subDir2.FullName, newDestinationDir, true) after this " foreach (FileInfo getFile in SubDirsFiles) {...}

Comment: The code is not correct. Please give a [mcve]. And thank you (not) for undoing my edit for clarity.

Comment: @DA , I can't do it that way, the parent folder must be there before copying its files. It will give me error saying that "Couldn't found the folder path for .... test.txt"

Comment: @JHBonarius the code works perfectly, I have days working with this code. I just wanted to make some changes to it's parent folder name.

Comment: `dir.GetDirectories();` <-- `dir` comes out of nowhere.

Comment: But you will have to create the directory for newDestinationFile + "_" + dictionary["XECM_DOC_TYPE"] if it is not there. Use  "CreateDirectory" before copy.

Comment: @JHBonarius, I thought you said I have to give a minimal reproducible example and I thought that was it. Anyway, that comes from `var dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir);`

Comment: @DA. newDestinationFile is a combined strings that give me a path which it has the path of the parent folder + the fileName, so it will be like this:  Path.Combine("C:\testFolder\" + "myFile.txt")

Comment: Sure.... but is "testFolder" there? and what if you will have another subfolder? Don't you have to create it?

Comment: @DA of course I have to create it, and I do create it in the beginning of the code but with another name. My point is to give that testFolder a name that is taken form C:\testFolder\myFile.txt so it will be something like this: C:\testFolder + "_" + "something" \myFile.txt

Comment: How is it "reproducible" if we don't have all the code to reproduce it? Please follow the link and read what is stated at that page. An excerpt: _"…Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself"_. This is a requirement by StackOverflow itself.

Comment: @JHBonarius, have you ever experienced this kind of scenario in your career? I mean, passing data from a child function to the parent function ?

Comment: _"passing data from a child function to the parent function"_: Of course. Usually you do that in a return statement. Or using an `out` parameter/pointer/reference.

Comment: @jhbonarius can you access the edit history?

Comment: @CaiusJard of course, but I'm not going to merge the two edits. TBH I have other things to do.

Comment: @questioner9928 I don't really understand the problem; these are file info objects that carry the full path. If you want to rename the parent folder, get its current name from the object's full path and choose a different name

Comment: @JHBonarius well, if so don't bother to suggest edits or giving "minimal reproductive example" just to get some reputation points. Take care.

Comment: @CaiusJard, the problem is that the parent folder is created under another name in the beginning of the code, then I am copying it's child files. And now I want to change it's name before the creation of the parent folder. So --- Read child folder, get a name, create a parent folder under a desired name, then copy the child under the parent folder. A pseudo code would look like this but I don't know whether I can jump into loops just like that.

Comment: Can you help me out a little by giving an example path or two and how you want them transforming? In my mind you just form the new root location, strip the old root off the full file path and build a new path on a new root

Comment: It's like this:  Parent Folder -> `string oldPath = "c:\user\test"` --- I copy this folder into a new Directory, then I go for its files for which their path would be  `string newPath = oldPath +File.Name`.  Now I read the Files inside that parent folder I get an important value which I would like to pass it on "higher level" and give it to the parent folder (which already is copied and which already (logically) has a name. But according to my code and to me... this looks kinda messy.